# ¿Es posible crear una barra de progreso con VB excel, pero con imagenes?

Tags: vba

tengo 5 imágenes que forman un logo y necesito que vaya completandose a medida que los textboxs se van completando en el formulario. alguna ayuda ?

Gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas,

La solución que le veo a tu problema es colocar las 5 imágenes en 5 PictureBox diferentes e ir poniendo en visible los PictureBox mientras se van introduciendo los datos en los TextBox.